# iOS - make a Toolbar stick to the bottom with scroll

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a normal UIViewController with a Navigation Bar on top that scrolls with the rest of the view when I scroll down. 
Now I want to add another toolbar that does the exact same but sticks to the bottom. Ultimately I want the view to scroll down (I have a lot of content), with a Navigation bar at the top and a Toolbar at the bottom that follow the rest of the view.

I have my toolbar ready with all the items but I don't know how to stick it to the bottom. Any help?

Thank you very much

Comment: Pin it to the view controller's view with constraints. Done.

Comment: May sound outdated but I don't use Auto Layout...

Comment: "May sound outdated" Yep. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have my toolbar ready with all the items but I don't know how to stick it to the bottom.

Just make sure that the toolbar isn't inside the scroll view. Only the views that are part of the scroll view's content will scroll, and those views that are not part of the scroll view's content will not scroll -- they'll "stick" to their respective positions in the window.

Comment: Actually, it's not what the toolbar is inside of that matters, but how it is positioned. The toolbar _can_ be inside the scroll view and still remain stationary, provided it is pinned by constraints to the scroll view's superview.